# Project structure does not show messages

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.2

Even after upgrading to 2.2.beta2, project structure dialog in android studio does not show messages tab

Here is how my project structure dialog looks like

[image: Project dialog structure]

Please note that the project was originally created on Android Studio 2.0

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, No. I've not explored it further